# Image button misplaces when clicking Infer Constrains

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I am having a problem with Android Studio. I have everything settled but when I click Infer Constraints, the image buttons misplaces. I could not find any solutions on Internet.

Here is the picture.

[image: This is the picture of it. First photo is before I click infer constraints and second is after.]`

Answer (score 0):

Try this... For the right image button, Don't set the edit text and centre button as constraints... Set the top and bottom of your layout as you did for the bill amount and place it near the centre image button...